# AngularJs : two page routing won't work for changing views , status code : 404

Tags: json, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-routing, ng-view

As a newbie in Angular, i am working a tutorial : WEB DEVELOPMENT WITH_ANGULARJS AND BOOTSTRAP via "Packt".

Below is the link in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/e0Jwt9ArCsYIrQCnM9fp?p=preview) to check the code implementation.

At the moment i am working on the Routing Events, specificly a login form where i added 2 links to change the view from the Login form to Report.
The error i receive is when i click on these links it returns :

```
{ "statusCode": 404,"error": "Not Found"}
```

Furthermore the data binding for the "report" template won't work as well.

The version of Angular that is been used in the tutorial is `AngularJs v1.3.0`, however i am using `v1.4.6` and no problem have been occurred so far!

While most of the similar issue posts refer to a version compatibility issue , in my case any version of Angular i used it produces the same error.

Have i done anything wrong in the script.js configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The href's you are using don't include the hash and proper angular path.

Change:

```
<a href="login">Login</a>
<a href="report">Report</a>
```

To:

```
<a href="#/login">Login</a>
<a href="#/report">Report</a>
```

Comment: That solved the half of my issue , now the links do work efficiently but the binding issue still remains! 
In any case i appreciate your help & thank you!